# Cross join 2 tables but include a null row

Tags: mysql, sql, cross-join

I'd like to combine 2 tables, get a row for every combo between the 2 tables, including a null row (? -> not sure how to describe this, an empty row).  A cross join gets me the combo's, but no null row.

| Table 1 |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |

| Table 2 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Expected result

| Table 1 | Table 2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| A | null |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| B | null |
| C | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| C | null |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `union` within a *subquery* to add your null row

With tables `t1` with `col1` and `t2` with `col2`

```
select * from t1 
cross join (
  select col2 from t2 union all select null
) t2
order by col1, col2
```

Comment: Tnx, just came to post it myself, came to the same conclusion (should have thought a bit harder before asking :).  But above indeed works and gets what I need.